# Joda LocalDateTime IllegalFieldValueException when converting to java.util.Date

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using JodaTime for the first time and don't understand what is wrong with this:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(1965, 4, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18);
Date date = localDateTime.toDate();
```

when I run this I get:

```
org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value -982 for millisOfSecond must be in the range [0,999]
```

but if I do this (no millis), I don't get the exception:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(1965, 4, 8, 15, 16, 17);
Date date = localDateTime.toDate();
```

And I don't get the exception with (i.e year = 1975):

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(1975, 4, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18);
Date date = localDateTime.toDate();
```

What's going on? Are there some restrictions about converting to java.util.Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(1965, 4, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18);
  Date date = localDateTime.toDateTime().toDate();
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this works. If you can explain why this is necessary I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: I think this is bug of `JodaTime 2+`. I am using `JodaTime 1.6`, and I havn't method `toDate()` in `LocalDateTime` class.

Comment: Yes, I found bug. It's in method `LocalDateTime#fromDateFields` in line `(int) (date.getTime() % 1000)`

Comment: Method `getTime` return value less then 0, becouse you date is before `1970 year`

Comment: So `date.getTime() % 1000 < 0`. But if you set millis = 0 in constructor, then `date.getTime() % 1000 = 0` and all works well

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks! Good spot on version 2.0, which is indeed the version of JodaTime I am using.

Comment: Fixed in GitHub - https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/commit/a9f1ae91311276c5321e23f880aa3b0078e1d191

Answer (score 1):

The following is usually right. But not this time.

<strike>Always use `.getMillis()` in Joda - it will give you millisecond time range from Epoch and allow flawless (Java API) `Date()` construction - like this: `new Date(millis)`.</strike>

So, summing up:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(1975, 4, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18);
Date date = new Date(localDateTime.getLocalMillis());
```

This is the solution that actually works:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime( 1975, 4, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18 );        
DateTime dt = new DateTime( ldt.getYear(), ldt.getMonthOfYear(), ldt.getDayOfMonth(), ldt.getHourOfDay(), ldt.getMinuteOfHour(), ldt.getSecondOfMinute(), ldt.getMillisOfSecond());
Date d = new Date( dt.getMillis() );
```

And 1965 is before Epoch... i don't know how it affects Date and millis, but, yeah, just saying.

Comment: I don't see a getLocalMillis() nor a getMillis() on localDateTime.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it is the method of `LocalDate`. Try `LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(1975, 4, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18); DateTime dt = new DateTime(ldt); Date d = new Date(dt.getMillis());` and let me know if it's ok

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. There is no constructor for DateTime that takes a LocalDateTime. I'm working round my issue by not bothering with millis but it would be nice to understand what the restrictions/limitations in JodaTime are.

Comment: @DaveRlz ok, I finally have working solution. Let me update my answer.